# easy_install does not work in Windows 7

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have Python 2.6.4 installed in C:\Python26.

I have PyQt4 installed from here: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-Py2.6-gpl-4.7.7-1.exe

I have added this path to %PATH%:

```
C:\Python26;C:\Python26\Scripts
```

When I type this command in cmd.exe however:

```
easy_install cheetah
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Richard>easy_install cheetah
'easy_install' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Richard>
```

Any help? In Windows XP it worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it lives here: `c:\python\scripts\easy_install.exe`

---

Later: okay, have you installed `easy_install`? Download the appropriate Windows installer for your python version [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows). (If you have no `scripts` directory, then you probably have not installed `easy_install`.)

Comment: I did that, too. There is no Scripts directory in C:\Python26.

Comment: easy_install is not installed when you install Python. If easy_install was properly installed (using the information hughdbrown linked), there will be a Scripts directory.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `C:\Python26\Scripts` path to `%PATH%`. `easy_install.exe` should be there.

Comment: I did that, too. There is no Scripts directory in C:\Python26.

Answer (score 1):

had a problem that's related.

i added a space after the semicolon and then typed in the scripts directory. easy_install didn't work until i removed the space.

ie. C:\Python26; C:\Python26\Scripts
does not work...

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure easy_install is installed located at `$Pythonpath\Scripts`
2. Add `$Pythonpath\Scripts` to `%PATH%`. How to do this can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/1750173
3. Restart command prompt.