# Python pip installation easy_install not recognized

Tags: python, windows, package, pip, easy-install

i installed setuptools from here:

```
pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
```

i go to my command line and enter easy_install but it says `easy_install is not recognized`,

anyone knows what is happening here? i got no error message when installing setuptools.

I am using windows,

any help would be appreciated

Comment: If it's on Windows you'll find some duplicates on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961047/easy-install-does-not-work-in-windows-7

Comment: Do you have `Python` scripts folders in your `PATH` environment variable ?

Comment: in the python folder i have a scripts folder that contains easy_install.exe

Comment: but when i run it, nothing happens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to Add your `scripts` folder in your python installation folder to your PATH variable, for example if your python is installed in `C:\Python27` you should do this :

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Go to `Edit system environment variables`
3. In the `Advanced` tab click on `Environment Variables`
4. find `PATH` variable and add `;C:\Python27\scripts` to the end of it